# Textures overlapping

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I am new in LibGDX and I would like to know how to make one texture appear in front of the other, because lets say we have 2 textures(t1 and t2) with shape of a square. And when they overlap, I see the color of t1 but I would like to see the color of t2? Is there any way that I can make some kind of priorities or?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just draw your texture in `render()` function in needed order. Last drawn texture will be on the first visible layer.  Example: (if the texture have the same size, you will see only second one):

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    spriteBatch.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    spriteBatch.draw(YOUR_TEXTURE_1, 0, 0);
    spriteBatch.draw(YOUR_TEXTURE_2, 0, 0);
        spriteBatch.end();
}
```

Comment: I already tried that but because I am using loop for drawing textures it sometimes takes first texture, than second and sometimes in different order.